# Does $K(n)$ detect minimal $K(n)$-local cell structures?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, stable-homotopy, chromatic-homotopy

Let $X$ be a finite spectrum, and let $N = dim_{\mathbb F_p} H_\ast(X;\mathbb F_p)$. I believe that $p$-completion $X^\wedge_p$ may be built as an $N$-cell complex where the cells are shifts of the $p$-complete sphere $S^\wedge_p$. That is, there is an $N$-step filtration $0 = X_0 \to X_1 \to \cdots \to X_N$ where the associated graded has a shift of $S^\wedge_p$ at each step.

**Question 1:** Let $X$ be a finite spectrum, and let $N = dim_{K(n)_\ast}K(n)_\ast X$. Then can the $K(n)$-localization $L_{K(n)} X$ be built as an $N$-cell complex where the cells are shifts of the $K(n)$-local sphere $L_{K(n)} S$?

**Question 2:** Same, but don't assume that $X$ is finite; only assume that $N$ is finite.

The spectra considered in Question 2 are the closure of those considered in Question 1 under retracts.

If it makes a difference to work $T(n)$-locally rather than $K(n)$-locally, that would be interesting.

Comment: A counterexample is given by the "upside-down question mark complex" (the cofiber of the extension of $\eta$ to a map $\Sigma S/(2) \rightarrow S$), whose $K(1)$-localization generates the exotic subgroup of the $K(1)$-local Picard group at $p=2$. I think the right question to ask is: if $dim_{K(n)_\ast} K(n)_\ast X = N$, can $L_{K(n)}X$ be built as an $N$-cell complex, where the cells are elements of the $K(n)$-local Picard group (i.e. have $1$-dimensional $K(n)$-homology)?

Comment: Hovey–Strickland’s Y spectrum is again a problem for Question 2, even allowing for William’s modification, as it was a problem in this older question of yours: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/363652/chromatic-minimal-cell-structures

Comment: oh wow I duplicated myself.

Comment: I initially deleted this post as a duplicate, but I have referred back to the comments here so many times in the past year that I think I should undelete it and just leave it as CW in case anybody else finds the comments as useful as I have.